# Convert String to TCHAR*?

Tags: c++, string, winapi

I'm attempting to use the C++ function `CreateProcessW` to generate another process in a Windows 10 system.

I first tested the following example code according to [the official example on the Microsoft page describing the `CreateProcessW` function](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/win32/procthread/creating-processes):

```
#include <windows.h>
#include <stdio.h>
#include <tchar.h>

void _tmain(int argc, TCHAR* argv[])
{
    STARTUPINFO si;
    PROCESS_INFORMATION pi;

    ZeroMemory(&si, sizeof(si));
    si.cb = sizeof(si);
    ZeroMemory(&pi, sizeof(pi));

    bool result = CreateProcess(NULL, argv[1], NULL, NULL, FALSE, 0, NULL, NULL, &si, &pi);

    if (!result)
    {
        printf("CreateProcess failed (%d).\n", GetLastError());

        return;
    }

    WaitForSingleObject(pi.hProcess, INFINITE);
 
    CloseHandle(pi.hProcess);
    CloseHandle(pi.hThread);
}
```

The setup above allows me to launch a command via the command prompt for the child process to execute without issues.

However, instead of supplying the child process with commands via the command prompt only, I wish to be able to send the child process commands that are stored in string variables of type `std::string` or `const char*`.

I see that the `CreateProcessW` function accepts the execution command for it's child process as a `LPWSTR` type, which as far as I can see appears to be a string literal of `TCHAR` types, which appears to define the `t_wchar` character type.

Simply trying to typecast `(LPWSTR)"test.exe"` or `(TCHAR*)"test.exe"` results in an `Access violation error`.

What is the proper way to convert a `std::string` or `const char*` type to a `LPWSTR` or `TCHAR*` type?

Thanks for reading my post, any guidance is appreciated.

Comment: There is little point in converting the string, it doesn't get any better at representing text.  Just use CreateProcessA().

Comment: If you want to use `CreateProcessW`, you also want to use `std::wstring`. With a 'w' in both. Or in none of them, like Hans suggests.

Comment: I voted to close as a duplicate because the question as asked already has answers. But depending on what you really need to achieve the question could be different and Hans of BoP’s comments are more applicable.

Comment: A `char*` string will end with a single null byte, but a `wchar_t` string will need two null bytes because its characters are larger.  That probably explains your Access Violation error.  But fixing that simple problem wouldn't help, because your strings would still be undecipherable.

Comment: The official [documentation](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/win32/api/processthreadsapi/nf-processthreadsapi-createprocessw) tells you what the issue is: *"The Unicode version of this function, `CreateProcessW`, can modify the contents of this string. Therefore, this parameter cannot be a pointer to read-only memory (such as a `const` variable or a literal string). **If this parameter is a constant string, the function may cause an access violation.**"*

Comment: The "t" API (TCHAR, tmain etc) is a vestige of Windows 95. It makes zero sense today.

Comment: Thanks for all the answers. While the suggested post by @tinman does solve my issue, I couldn't just supply a `std::wstring` variable into `CreateProcessW`. I additionally had to call `c_str` and typecast the result of that to `TCHAR*`.

Comment: Don't cast. Just call `CreateProcessW` (rather than going through the generic-text mapping macro `CreateProcess`).

Comment: Oh, the intention behind the cast is to remove the `const` qualifier. The same advice applies: Don't.  Pass [`s.data()`](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/string/basic_string/data) (for C++17 and later), or `&s[0]` otherwise.

Comment: I see that the `wstring_convert` converter is deprecated in C++ 17 and later. However, I also see that there are many people stating that it shouldn't be so, and that it's one of the only methods of performing the conversions. Should I be worried about the deprecated state of the `wstring_convert` converter?

Comment: @Runsva A windows specific alternative would be `MultiByteToWideChar`. You give it the char* and the code page of a string and it outputs the wide characters.

Comment: What text encoding is in these strings? Is it UTF8?

Answer (score 2):

It takes some research and experience to get your head around `TCHAR` and its relationship to `char` and `wchar_t` (and all the MSFT acronyms you'll come across for handling strings, like `LPCTSTR`, `LPWSTR`, and many others).

It's not clear why you need to handle strings as `char`-based, however. Maybe you have a legitimate reason, but I'm skeptical.

Modern Windows (basically, anything for at least the past 25+ years) relies on UTF-16 for handling strings internally. The short story is that, if you call the ANSI version of a function in the WinAPI (the ones ending with "A", like `CreateProcessA`), the OS will actually call the "W" version at runtime (such as `CreateProcessW()`). Your `char`-based strings will therefore be converted to `wchar_t`-based strings anyway, which is how UTF-16 strings are stored in Windows.

It's not efficient to do things this way, and you normally shouldn't (unless you really do have a legitimate reason). MSFT itself says you normally shouldn't. You also normally shouldn't be converting `char`-based strings to `wchar_t`-based strings on-the-fly. You should normally rely on `wchar_t`-based strings in the first place instead, which is what `TCHAR` resolves to by default.

Google for the `UNICODE` and `_UNICODE` based `#define`'d constants, which will normally be cited in any sufficiently detailed article about the purpose of `TCHAR` and string handling in the WinAPI.

It's a painful learning experience, unfortunately.

Comment: The whole `TCHAR` debacle came about a long time ago, when Microsoft was trying to make it easy for everyone to convert their programs to Unicode.  But as you say it's been a hindrance rather than a help for quite a while, and I'd say 25 years is being conservative.

Comment: @Mark Yes, as any veteran MSFT C++ developer will know, TCHAR was introduced so you could compile for either ANSI or UTF-16, with the eventual goal at the time of the latter. We're a full generation past that now but it's still baked into much (most) of the WinAPI, and a source of major confusion for many developers. It always has been but it's even worse for today's generation IMHO (since it's a costly throwback to ancient times that even fewer now have the patience or time to learn).

Comment: I will point out too that there's another model too, keep your strings as `char *` in UTF-8 and only convert when you need to make an API call.  I think it's a great idea, but I don't know anybody that works that way.  http://utf8everywhere.org/

Comment: The entire *"UTF-8 Everywhere"* manifesto is based on the (provably false) idea that everyone was using UTF-8 already. This isn't true. Windows uses UTF-16. Java does. So does .NET. And ECMAScript. That's **a lot** of UTF-16. UTF-8 is a fine character encoding for *data interchange*. For your *internal* encoding, however, I cannot see a reason ever not to use UTF-16 on Windows.